# type object 'Attribute' has no attribute 'option'

Tags: django, django-models

hello i am trying to call the foreign key 'option' charfield which is a choice field but getting the above error

here is models.py

```
class Color(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.ForeignKey('Attribute')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = ColorManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product' , 'value')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Attribute(models.Model):
    OPTION_CATEGORIES = (
        ('color' , 'color') , 
        ('size' , 'size') , 
        ('type' , 'type') , 
        ('sleeves' , 'sleeves') , 
        )
    option = models.CharField(max_length=100 , choices = OPTION_CATEGORIES)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.option
```

here is views.py

```
Color.objects.get_or_create(product=instance ,name=Attribute.option.color , value=color)
```

here is the traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\plump\Plumpin\src\products\views.py" in DataEntry
  287.                 Color.objects.get_or_create(product=instance ,name=Attribute.option.color , value=color)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dataentry/dataentry
Exception Value: type object 'Attribute' has no attribute 'option'
```

Attribute table has an attribute called option but still it is giving the above error

Answer (score 0):

From your traceback;

In views.py

```
Color.objects.get_or_create(product=instance ,name=Attribute.option.color , value=color)
```

Here name should be an object, something like this;

```
Color.objects.get_or_create(product=instance ,name=Attribute.objects.get(option='color') , value='color')
```

Comment: it returns 2 objects ...as the attribute table has 2 colors

Comment: the name should be assigned either as 'size' 'color'  ie as OPTION_CATEGORIES

Comment: Then you have to change name to CharField instead of ForeignKey and directly assign like;

Color.objects.get_or_create(product=instance ,name='color' , value='color')